# How does PlotLegends actually work with ListPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I'm sensing this might be a rookie mistake but normally I roll my own legends but decided to try the built in legends for a `ListPlot3D`. `PlotLegends` is listed as an option for `ListPlot3D` but curiously in V9 there are no usage examples. On the other hand there are several examples for `Plot3D`. Specifically I was trying to create a legend analogous to this example from the `Plot3D` docs.

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[x y], {y, 0, 3, 0.1}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

However I want to use my own specific `ColorFunction` but it appears that as soon as you depart from the named built-in string colour functions `PlotLegends` ceases to work.

I know how to "roll my own" so I am not seeking assistance with creating my own function. I simply want to know if it is possible to make something similar using the built in options for `ListPlot3D`, whether I am overlooking something or whether this is a bug.

**Edit**

From Wolfram: *the current design of the PlotLegends -> Automatic option is to turn off the plot legend when a pure function (as `ColorFunction`) is present.*

which means that this

```
With[{cf = Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, #] &,
data = Table[Sin[x y], {y, 0, 3, 0.1}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}]},
    ListPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> cf, 
        PlotLegends -> Automatic
    ]
]
```

doesn't work ...which would appear to make it a design oversight rather than a bug.

Comment: Feels very bug-like to me ...  can't really see why it couldn't work, especially after looking at rm's example.  EDIT: Works for the completely analogous DensityPlot, but not for Plot3D.  I'd say that settles it's a bug.

Comment: @Szabolcs the answer from rm -rf works but it *does* seem like a bug that `Automatic` doesn't work for a valid user `ColorFunction`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have your own color function, then passing an explicit `BarLegend` to `PlotLegends` seems to be the only way out. This also means that you'll have to feed the min/max for your data, but this isn't hard. Here's an example:

```
With[{cf = Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, #] &, data = Table[Sin[x y], {y, 0, 3, 0.1}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}]},
    ListPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> cf, 
        PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cf, Through[{Min, Max}@data]}]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: This works. Shame the `Automatic` option doesn't work given that it does for the built in `ColorFunction`s.