# Customizing the look of a ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I show my data bellow, and I want to use `ListPlot3D` to make a plot of that data. In this process I have some problems that I will discuss them step by step:

```
list={{0., 0.2, 0.1}, {0., 0.4, 0.2}, {0., 0.6, 0.3}, {0., 0.8, 0.4}, {0., 
 1., 0.5}, {0., 1.2, 0.6}, {0., 1.4, 0.7}, {0., 1.6, 0.8}, {0., 1.8, 
 0.9}, {0., 2., 1.}, {0.2, 0., 0.0267949}, {0.2, 0.4, 
 0.0645751}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.14641}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.23589}, {0.2, 1., 
 0.32915}, {0.2, 1.2, 0.4245}, {0.2, 1.4, 0.52111}, {0.2, 1.6, 
 0.618535}, {0.2, 1.8, 0.716515}, {0.2, 2., 0.814889}, {0.4, 0., 
 0.0535898}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.0394449}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.0582576}, {0.4, 0.8,
 0.12915}, {0.4, 1., 0.208276}, {0.4, 1.2, 0.29282}, {0.4, 1.4, 
 0.381025}, {0.4, 1.6, 0.47178}, {0.4, 1.8, 0.564365}, {0.4, 2., 
 0.658301}, {0.6, 0., 0.0803848}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.0708497}, {0.6, 0.4, 
 0.0432236}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.0557439}, {0.6, 1., 0.12111}, {0.6, 1.2, 
 0.193725}, {0.6, 1.4, 0.27178}, {0.6, 1.6, 0.353939}, {0.6, 1.8, 
 0.43923}, {0.6, 2., 0.526943}, {0.8, 0., 0.10718}, {0.8, 0.2, 
 0.1}, {0.8, 0.4, 0.0788897}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.0450166}, {0.8, 1., 
 0.0544004}, {0.8, 1.2, 0.116515}, {0.8, 1.4, 0.184886}, {0.8, 1.6, 
 0.258301}, {0.8, 1.8, 0.335782}, {0.8, 2., 0.416553}, {1., 0., 
 0.133975}, {1., 0.2, 0.12822}, {1., 0.4, 0.111181}, {1., 0.6, 
 0.0834849}, {1., 0.8, 0.0460608}, {1., 1.2, 0.0535654}, {1., 1.4, 
 0.113553}, {1., 1.6, 0.178983}, {1., 1.8, 0.249}, {1., 2., 
 0.322876}, {1.2, 0., 0.16077}, {1.2, 0.2, 0.155969}, {1.2, 0.4, 
 0.141699}, {1.2, 0.6, 0.118335}, {1.2, 0.8, 0.0864471}, {1.2, 1., 
 0.0467437}, {1.2, 1.4, 0.0529964}, {1.2, 1.6, 0.111488}, {1.2, 1.8, 
 0.174773}, {1.2, 2., 0.242221}, {1.4, 0., 0.187564}, {1.4, 0.2, 
 0.183447}, {1.4, 0.4, 0.171179}, {1.4, 0.6, 0.151}, {1.4, 0.8, 
 0.123285}, {1.4, 1., 0.0885123}, {1.4, 1.2, 0.0472251}, {1.4, 1.6, 
 0.0525839}, {1.4, 1.8, 0.109967}, {1.4, 2., 0.171623}, {1.6, 0., 
 0.214359}, {1.6, 0.2, 0.210756}, {1.6, 0.4, 0.2}, {1.6, 0.6, 
 0.182255}, {1.6, 0.8, 0.157779}, {1.6, 1., 0.126908}, {1.6, 1.2, 
 0.0900331}, {1.6, 1.4, 0.0475825}, {1.6, 1.8, 0.0522712}, {1.6, 2., 
 0.108801}, {1.8, 0., 0.241154}, {1.8, 0.2, 0.23795}, {1.8, 0.4, 
 0.228377}, {1.8, 0.6, 0.212549}, {1.8, 0.8, 0.190652}, {1.8, 1., 
 0.162929}, {1.8, 1.2, 0.129671}, {1.8, 1.4, 0.0911993}, {1.8, 1.6, 
 0.0478585}, {1.8, 2., 0.0520259}, {2., 0., 0.267949}, {2., 0.2, 
 0.265065}, {2., 0.4, 0.25644}, {2., 0.6, 0.24216}, {2., 0.8, 
 0.222361}, {2., 1., 0.197224}, {2., 1.2, 0.16697}, {2., 1.4, 
 0.131846}, {2., 1.6, 0.0921216}, {2., 1.8, 0.0480779}};
```

1-The first question:

In an insane way, I have used the [Toad answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42262/how-does-plotlegends-actually-work-with-listplot3d) for plotting:

```
ticks[min_, max_] := 
 Table[If[EvenQ[i], {i, i, .06, Red}, {i, i, .02, Blue}], {i, 
Ceiling[min], Floor[max], 1}];
With[{cf = Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, #] &, 
 data = Table[Sin[x y], {y, 0, 3, 0.1}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}]}, 
 ListPlot3D[list, ColorFunction -> cf, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"i", "k", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)"}, 
 Ticks -> ticks[2, 1], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14, Bold, Thickness[0.003]], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"]]]
```

`Sin[x y]` is not related to my `list` but the code does not work by deleting that or being replaced by my `list` as data. I just want to use the color scheme (defined by Toad) because I like it. How can I use of this color scheme (or a more impactful one) without introducing `Sin[x y]`?

2- the second question:

(I Can't remember where I found `ticks[min_, max_]`) With `ticks[min_, max_]`, I want to show more ticks on the axes of the plot and give them custom length and thickness, but there is no difference between `ticks[2, 1]` and `ticks[2, 2]` and `ticks[5, 1]`.

3- The third question:

The shape of my plot is as shown bellow, but the axes labeling such as `i`, `k`, and `P1` are encroaching on the numbers along the axes. I can separate them by using a smaller font, but I prefer the larger fonts as more readable. How can I adjust the distance between the labels and numbers?

[image: polt]

4- the fourth question:

I want to highlight the data on the plot which along a slice through the surface at `j = 1`, as shown bellow, but I am not able to show that. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me first of all note that using Mma requires some homework made. Most of the questions you put have the answers in the documentation. So, do have a look.

Your question 1: Sin has nothing to do with the color scheme. In the code you copied the latter is fixed by `cf = Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, #] &`, while `data...`only fixes the array of points presumably used in the example you site. You should have a look into `Menu/Help/DocumentationCenter/ListPlot3D/Options/ColorFunction` and probably into `Menu/Help/DocumentationCenter/ColorSchemes` to get more information and see "...more impactful design colored...". You will find a lot there.

Your 2nd question: You should check `Menu/Help/DocumentationCenter/Ticks/Examples`.

Your 3rd and 4th questions: First evaluate your cell contaning `list` and the function `ticks` definitions. Then let us form a list with k=0.....2 [0,2] and with just fixed i=1:

```
 list2 = Select[list, #[[1]] == 1 &]

(*   {{1., 0., 0.133975}, {1., 0.2, 0.12822}, {1., 0.4, 0.111181}, {1., 
  0.6, 0.0834849}, {1., 0.8, 0.0460608}, {1., 1.2, 0.0535654}, {1., 
  1.4, 0.113553}, {1., 1.6, 0.178983}, {1., 1.8, 0.249}, {1., 2., 
  0.322876}}   *)
```

Then evaluate the following:

```
    Show[{
  With[{cf = Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, #] &}, 
   ListPlot3D[list, ColorFunction -> cf, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {Column[{Spacer[5], Style["i", 18, Italic]}], 
      Row[{Style["k", 18, Italic], Spacer[5]}], 
      Row[{Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)", 18, Italic], 
        Spacer[10]}]}, Ticks -> ticks[2, 1], 
    TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14, Bold, Thickness[0.003]], 
    AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"]]],
  Graphics3D[{Yellow, Thickness[0.01], Line[list2]}]
  }]
```

yielding this.

[image]

Note that the offset of the i, k etc. from the axes is defined by the argument of `Spacer`in the constructs like

```
    Row[{Spacer[10], Style["k", 18, Italic]}]
```

while the yellow line - by the statement:

```
Graphics3D[{Yellow, Thickness[0.01], Line[list2]}]
```

Have fun!

**Later edit**: to address your later question. Try this:

```
Graphics3D[{Directive[Dashed, Purple, Thickness[0.005]], Line[list2]}]
```

giving the following:

[image]

Comment: I think All your address for help document center are similar.

Comment: @Ackaran  They all are in the DocumentationCenter, that is right. But they have all different last key word, or few last key words. That's, what counts.

Comment: besides so much thanks for your help, an amazing problem please pay attention to: Graphics3D[{Dashed, 
  Line[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {4, 4, 1}}]}]; But when I write Graphics3D[{Purple, Thickness[0.005], Line[list2], Dashed}]; Unfortunately, dashing doesn't work!!!!

Comment: @Ackaran  Welcome. Have a look at the edits for the last question.

Comment: Nice, So much nice,